# Adding a specific number of WORKING DAYS to a date in Business Objects

Tags: oracle9i, business-objects

I'm am trying to find a method of adding a specific number of working days to a date in Business Objects - either a universe object or report object is acceptable. This is not a case of calculating business days between 2 dates but taking a start date and adding X working days to get a result date, taking into account weekends and bank holidays (we have a calendar table which flags working days but notably does not have a countable ID field). Essentially i need a direct copy of the NETWORKDAYS() function in Excel.

Again I stress this is about adding working days to a start date, not calculating between 2 days, for which there are a number of solutions already available. If anyone has some suggestions or can point to a solution i'd be most grateful!

For info we are using Business Objects XI 3.1 sp5 and our database is Oracle 9.

Regards,

Chizo Ejindu

Comment: I don't know oracle or business objects, but could you use the function for the difference by, say, using a binary search to find the date that would give the right difference?

Comment: Do you have the option of creating a function in the database?

Comment: I cannot directly create a function in the DB, our DB is managed by an external company. Whilst i know there are solutions available via a function i do not think my manager would be willing to incur the costs involved to get our supplier to develop a new function - money is extremely tight in the public sector! I will enquire but i would prefer a business objects solution if possible - if it's not possible then we'll have no choice i guess :)

Comment: Not aware of a Business Objects solution, XI3.1 SP4 on Oracle 10g here, also public sector. My solution to your problem involved a couple of PL/SQL functions.

Comment: Would you be OK with a prompt asking you for a start date and the number of working days to add? Thus it would only work for a single date at a time.

Comment: Hi Kristof - unfortunately no, i needed this to work across a table of dates rather than one date at a time. However unbeknownst to me our database supplier created a function to do exactly what i required, they eventually told me of it's existence and that solved this requirement. I cannot however let you know how it works as they haven't told me!

Comment: Can you please provide info about your 'calendar' table. I guess that some fancy SQL can get you there in an elegant way from a BO universe/report perspective... names/daratypes for columns and sample data over a weekend